# VBA COUNTIFS data with INDIRECT sheet references

Tags: excel, vba

I have quite a big xlsm sheet with lots of data from different sources. In that sheet I often use Countif with Indirect. All works well, but now when the sheet has grown, the autocalculations are killing excel.

I want to setup it so that it makes these COUNTIFS on demand, by a button click.

This is one example that works as a normal formula and I would like to have it in VBA:
`'COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$C$4&"'!"&"$J:$J");A9)'`

Answer (score 0):

1st proposal: turn off automatic calculation (excel 2010: Formulas -> calculation options) and then 
make a command button to calculate.

```html
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Calculate
    End Sub
```

2nd proposal: Just use VBA to enter result of your formulas to a cell:

```html
        Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Range("d5").Value = Evaluate("COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&$C$4&""'!""&""$J:$J"")," = "&$A$9)")
        End Sub
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: THanks for your reply. That has given a FALSE as in d5.

Comment: I did change that using static AT instead of A9 and few minor changes (tried many things) now, getting #VALUE! erorr `Range("d5").Value = Evaluate("COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&$C$4&""'!""&""$J:$J"");""AT"")")`